# unresolved external symbol while using wchar_t in managed c++ project

Tags: c++, mfc, c++-cli, wchar-t

I have one C++ project with settings of Unicode as character set and /clr option for common language run time support. I am calling some function of MFC dll (with setting of MultiByte character set) and I am getting some liking error on those functions which are using wchar_t. Same dll is working file for those unicode c++ projects where /clr option is not set (i.e. no common language run time support). I have done the google and tried some thing like:--

1. Replace Cstring with std:string but both are giving same error.

Example for std: string:--

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   CEventLog::CEventLog(wchar_t const *)" (??0CEventLog@@QAE@PB_W@Z)

for Cstring:--

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall
>   CIITAdoField::GetValue(class ATL::CStringT > > &)"
>   (?GetValue@CIITAdoField@@QAE_NAAV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall
>   Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::CacheLoader > >,class
>   Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::HolidayScheduleInfo,struct
>   Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::HolidayScheduleSpeedCacheParam>
>
> > ::Reload(class Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::DoubleKeyCacheInstance > >,class
> >     Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::HolidayScheduleInfo,struct
> >     Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::HolidayScheduleSpeedCacheParam> &,class
> >     CIITAdoRecordset &,enum
> >     Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::ERefreshType,class
> >     Iit::DataFeedSvr::SpeedCache::CacheObserver const *)"
> >     (?Reload@?$CacheLoader@V?$DoubleKeyCacheInstance@JV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@VHolidayScheduleInfo@SpeedCache@DataFeedSvr@Iit@@UHolidayScheduleSpeedCacheParam@456@@SpeedCache@DataFeedSvr@Iit@@@SpeedCache@DataFeedSvr@Iit@@QAE_NAAV?$DoubleKeyCacheInstance@JV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@VHolidayScheduleInfo@SpeedCache@DataFeedSvr@Iit@@UHolidayScheduleSpeedCacheParam@456@@234@AAVCIITAdoRecordset@@W4ERefreshType@234@PBVCacheObserver@234@@Z)

1. I have checked the setting like "Treat Wchar_t as Built in type" and it is file.
2. I have tried to explicitly export function and class using `__declspec(dllexport)` but no luck.
3. I can not change my project from unicode to multibyte or can not change the setting of /clr option as it starts giving other error.

Please suggest the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What all I can see from you error, ErrorLog constuctor defintion can not be find from client. 

Have you given the reference of your import library in project settings?

Comment: Yes..I have explictly added all libraries in project setting.

Answer (score -1):

Do a 'dumpbin' on the external DLL to see what's exported. If your CEventLog::CEventLog is not exporting a char based constructor you won't be able to import it, simple as that.

It doesn't look from your example that the /clr switch is causing the problem. Try creating a brand new Unicode project (without the CLR) just to check you really can link to the external DLL.

Comment: I have done the dumbbin and it seems that is exporting a char based constructor. 068 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ??0CEventLog@@QAE@PBD@Z (public: __thiscall CEventLog::CEventLog(char const *)). Please correct me if I am wrong. However there is one more thing that when I am using my same dll in other project which has same settings other than /clr option, it is building fine and thats why I am doubting on this switch.

Comment: Yep, that constructor only accepts chars. Are you using a std::string or std::wstring? Even with Unicode compiled std::string will still use chars not wchar_t.